# Beautiful Soup and pkg_resources

Tags: beautifulsoup, importerror, pkg-resources

I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup. I installed in my mac terminal easy_install following the instructions, and while the process seem to go fine, when I try to import from bs4,  had an ImportError, saying that such module did not exist.

I google it and after several tries, my terminal said that in order to use beautiful soup, somehow I should require that package from pkg_resources.

> "Because this distribution was installed --multi-version, before you
> can import modules from this package in an application, you will need
> to 'import pkg_resources' and then use a 'require()' call similar to
> one of these examples, in order to select the desired version:
>
> pkg_resources.require("beautifulsoup4")  # latest installed version"

So, I tried to import pkg_resources but that leaves to a dead road as well. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `pkg_resources` using `pip` for example before you can import it.

Comment: I know this is an old question,; I came across it searching for an answer to an unrelated question.